# How to resolve 'SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module' when exporting variables?

Tags: javascript, export

I am new at programming and currently building a project in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I want to export variables from one of my external JavaScript files to another one. However, I get an error from the console in Mozilla Firefox when trying it out. The error is: "SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module".

I have tried exporting at the beginning of my code, the end, and inside of a function (Where I want it to be exported from). I've looked online, but I can't seem to find any answers to this, just answers for importing.

```
function exports() {
    export { cakeChoicePricing, cakeTypeResultPricing };
    export { cupcakeChoicePricing, cupcakeTypeResultPricing };
};
```

Importing Below:

```
import { cakeChoicePricing, cakeTypeResultPricing } from './JavaScript.js';
import { cupcakeChoicePricing, cupcakeTypeResultPricing } from './JavaScript.js';
```

Thank you for any help provided!

Update (Here is more of my code):

```
let cakeChoicePricing;
let cupcakeChoicePricing;
```

```
function dessertChoiceCake() {
        cakeElement.setAttribute('class', 'disabled'); //Set cake button to unclickable
        cakeChoicePricing = 'Cake';
        cupcakeChoicePricing = 'Cake';
}
```

```
let exportCake = document.getElementById("cakeReviewButton");
let exportCupcake = document.getElementById("cupcakeReviewButton");

exportCake.addEventListener("click", exports);
exportCupcake.addEventListener("click", exports);

function exports() {
    export { cakeChoicePricing, cakeTypeResultPricing };
    export { cupcakeChoicePricing, cupcakeTypeResultPricing };
};
```

Comment: What do you mean, you want the exports to be exported from a function? Can you post more context around how you want to use your `exports` function?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I did not show it here, but I would like to run the exports function after a certain button is clicked, which should then pass the variables to another file where I can display their values. I placed my exports in a function as I only want to export them after they have been modified through other parts of my code. I hope this clarifies things a little bit more, but if it doesn't, please let me know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code so we can see (in code) the sort of control flow you're looking for? Even if it's not working, it'll probably give us a better sense of what you're aiming to accomplish

Comment: the error message is quite clear - you can't export from within a function, that is not top-level code (don't think of top-level being at the begin of the file - top-level code begins in the first column of a line in *properly indented code* - and you can't export conditionally - which is obvious when you export from top-level code - re-think your code, re-think the import side

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sure, I just posted it in the question. Thank you.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you. That makes much more sense. However, even when I try to place my exports outside of the function, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: are you sure? you haven't show such code, all the code you've shown has the export in the wrong place - please add code to the question that demonstrates this new issue

Comment: @JaromandaX Here it is: `export { cakeChoicePricing, cakeTypeResultPricing };
export { cupcakeChoicePricing, cupcakeTypeResultPricing }; `

Comment: I think your control flow should be inverted. When the button is clicked, run a function which accepts *parameters* of `cakeChoicePricing`, etc.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you, that is a good idea. I am then just wondering how I will export the parameters if exports can not occur inside of a function, but I do not want them exported as soon as the script is run from the HTML.

Comment: "here it is" ... lol that wont export anything since those values don't exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider inverting your control flow. Rather than trying to export variables that don't exist yet, import a function from the other file instead, and then call that function with `cakeChoicePricing`, etc parameters when needed. For example:

```
import displayPrices from './prices';

const prices = {};

// when you need to, assign to properties of the prices object:

function dessertChoiceCake() {
  cakeElement.setAttribute('class', 'disabled'); //Set cake button to unclickable
  prices.cakeChoicePricing = 'Cake';
  prices.cupcakeChoicePricing = 'Cake';
}

const callDisplayPrices = () => {
  displayPrices(prices);
};

exportCake.addEventListener("click", callDisplayPrices);
exportCupcake.addEventListener("click", callDisplayPrices);
```

And have the `displayPrices` function (which the other file exports) handle the object with the prices properties, eg

```
export default (prices) => {
  console.log('cakeChoicePricing:', prices.cakeChoicePricing);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I just have a few questions, if you don't mind. What exactly is `displayPrices` supposed to do? And, is `callDisplayPrices` a function or a variable (or something else)? Finally, what does `prices.cakeChoicePricing = 'Cake';` do exactly? I am also having a bit of trouble understanding the `console.log` part. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: `displayPrices` is the function that you imported. Inside it, you put the code to display the prices. `callDisplayPrices` is a variable name bound to a function, which, when called, calls `callDisplayPrices` with the `prices` object. (putting `callDisplayPrices` into its own variable name helps keep code DRY, otherwise you'd have to repeat `'click', () => displayPrices(prices)` twice at the button)

Comment: Yes, it makes much more sense, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

When exporting, you must do so from the "scope" of the source file that you're exporting from rather than from a function as you currently are (ie from inside the `exports()` function) .

A simple fix would be to revise your `JavaScript.js` module so that the variables that you want to export (and import into another module), are directly exported when declared, at the top level of your `JavaScript.js` module:

**JavaScript.js**

```
// Start of JavaScript.js file - do not nest exports inside of any function, etc

export const cakeChoicePricing = // Some value or function
export const cakeTypeResultPricing = // Some value or function

export const cupcakeChoicePricing = // ..
export const cupcakeTypeResultPricing = // ..
```

**OtherModule**

```
// This can be merged into single import statement

import { 
    cakeChoicePricing, 
    cakeTypeResultPricing, 
    cupcakeChoicePricing, 
    cupcakeTypeResultPricing
} from './JavaScript.js';
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Perhaps I wasn't very clear in my question, but I want to only export these variables after having been modified in previous parts of the code and only when a certain button is pushed. I am trying to create something of an order system where the user chooses different options for cakes or cupcakes, such as Red Velvet cake, so `cakeTypeResultPricing = 'Red Velvet'` and display the final options on another HTML page. I hope this clears things up a little bit. Thank you.

Comment: `only when a certain button is pushed` you can't export conditionally - rethink your code instead - how can you import something that isn't yet exported?